# Regular expression to check it contains only alphanumerics but maximum only 2 digits, spaces are allowed and up to 1 hyphen,1 comma are allowed?

Tags: .net, regex

The string can have Alphabets [a-zA-Z]
It can have numbers [0-9] but min 0 and max 2
spaces are allowed
And for special characters max 1 hyphen, and max 1 comma

Comment: sorry - is that the question? :-(

Comment: Should it allow only English alphabetic characters or are characters such as "ö" or "ß" allowed?

Comment: @Critical Skill yes its a question

Comment: Does the position of the comma/hyphen matters? Or it can be at the start/end of the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. Here is one using look-ahead assertions:

```
^(?=[^ ]* ?[^ ]*(?: [^ ]*)?$)(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?=[^,]*,?[^,]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ,-]*$
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to note that this can be achieved easily without regular expressions, in a much more maintainable way (what would happen if next month you want 3 dashes and 5 digits - how would that regex look?).
Consider:

```
string s = "abcd2,6  ";
bool valid =
    (
        (s.Count(' '.Equals) <= 2) &&
        (s.Count(','.Equals) <= 1) &&
        (s.Count('-'.Equals) <= 1) &&
        (s.Count(char.IsDigit) <= 2)
    );
```

(even if you don't have linq this could be done easily)

If you also want to check for English letters you can match against `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,-]*$"` - this will check the characters but won't count them (I took a small bit from Gumbo's regex).